# When applying for a UK visa, how do I explain the US parole stamp on my passport?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, standard-visitor-visas, removal

In 2014, I worked on a cruise under a C1D visa, which was valid for 5 years. However, I resigned early from the cruise line, which made me have a parole stamp on my passport saying "DT Removed Under Safeguard."

This year, I'm traveling to the UK (I had been there a couple of times before the cruise job). There is a question on the visa application form that says "Have you ever been deported/removed from other countries beside the UK?" I have no idea if I have to answer Yes or No.

On my passport was stamped *Removed Under Safeguard* but I actually resigned from the job and willingly left the US. I didn't ever stay after the given visa conditions. I still have the evaluation paper that said I resigned from the cruise job.

Comment: I interpret that the C1D visa was removed by Safeguard, not you, o you never have been deported of removed.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi that's not quite correct: it's about the crew member not the C1D. The parole stamp shows that he was not admitted to the US. The removed under safeguard means that he left the US after going through a CBP  process for discharged crew (discharge includes resignation). He has, however, been refused entry and should include that in the UK visa application, just to be cautious.

Comment: @Giorgio How has he been refused entry?

Comment: @DJClayworth .. a crew member who leaves the vessel under discharge and not admitted to the US is escorted to a point of departure (airport) which is shown by his *Removed Under Safeguard*; otherwise, they'd be admitted per the C1D which allows transit (crew etc.) on their own.

Comment: @Giorgio but it isn't clear if the OP actually was *refused* admission to the US and removed under safeguard as a result or whether the OP simply *declined* to seek admission to the US after leaving the ship and was given the only alternative available, removal by safeguard.

Comment: @RobertColumbia At port, a vessel applies to CBP to discharge a nonimmigrant crew member (resigns, is terminated, goes on leave, or transferred to another vessel). In this case, the CBP officer ordered the crew member to be removed from the United States and the only way to do it is to have them escorted, as it’s impossible to do without setting foot on US soil. OP was allowed to transit for the sole purpose of going from vessel to airport, accompanied. When crew is discharged, the vessel (owner, master) requests; the crew member has no option (other than for medical emergency)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. This Removed Under Safeguard is so confusing. Maybe I'll answer know but add this detail into my cover letter concerning this stamp.

Comment: @OTongMandy I would answer yes, and have the explanation and paperwork. If you answer no, and it is viewed as you were, in fact, removed, then you would be further guilty of lying/deception. If you answer yes, and have your paperwork, then the CBP officer sees what happened and can check it off as a non-critical event.

Comment: Whenever UK Immigration ask you that blanked question _Have you ever been_, you better err on the side of full disclosure of even gray areas. I am talking from experience. Tick yes and provide an explanation with your application.

Comment: @CGCampbell not true. If he submits the passport with a stamp that says removed, he can not be "guilty (although that word is specifically used for court convictions)" of deception. Deception requires intent. The burden of proof in this case in on the ECO. On the other hand, if he were to avoid submitting that passport with the intent of deceiving the authorities, he would be thought to have practiced deception on the balance of probabilities.

Answer (score 9):

> Have you ever been deported/removed from other countries beside the UK?

Under the circumstances, you should answer *yes* as your resignation triggered a process required by US Customs and Border Patrol regulations. You had conditional access to US soil in order to go from the ship to your international departure flight.

You can add an explanation that ‘I resigned my job and was allowed to transit from vessel to airport.”

If needed, explain that, under US CPB regulations, a crew member who resigns must have CBP permission to leave the vessel, documents for onward country (passport/visa), and evidence of arrangements (airline tickets etc.). In your case, you were accompanied from the vessel to the airport and, as the only way to do that is landside (i.e., setting foot on US soil), the notation simply says that.

It's very likely that the UKVI understands this sort of action by US authorities, and does not consider it a strike against you. It is better to err on the side of caution and reference it, than to omit and a potential negative impact.